Check if 3 elements in an array are the same value
I am making a TicTacToe game (fairly easy I know but I am a beginner) and I am almost done, my problem now is I am trying to have it check if a row, a column or a diagonal of the table have the same value, and recursively keep playing if it is not. My board looks like this :
char xToken = 'x';
char oToken = 'o';
char vertical = '|';
char horizontal = '-';

class Board {
public:
    const static int rows = 6;
    const static int cols = 6;
    char grid[rows][cols]{};

    Board() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                grid[i][0] = '0' + i;
                grid[0][j] = '0' + j;

                if (j == 2 || j == 4) {
                    grid[i][j] = vertical;
                }

                if (i == 2 || i == 4) {
                    grid[i][j] = horizontal;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void printBoard() {
        for (auto & i : grid) {
            for (char j : i) {
                cout << j << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

This is my play() function:
void play() {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        cout << "choose index you want to play in" << endl;
        cout << "Player 1" << endl;
        cout << "Row: " << endl;
        cin >> i;
        cout << "Column: " << endl;
        cin >> j;
        cout << i << ", " << j << endl;
        if (Board().grid[i][j] != vertical && Board().grid[i][j] != horizontal) {
            grid[i][j] = xToken;
            printBoard();
        }

        cout << "choose index you want to play in" << endl;
        cout << "Player 2" << endl;
        cout << "Row: " << endl;
        cin >> i;
        cout << "Column: " << endl;
        cin >> j;
        cout << i << ", " << j << endl;
        if (Board().grid[i][j] != vertical && Board().grid[i][j] != horizontal) {
            grid[i][j] = oToken;
            printBoard();
        }

        if(grid[i][j] == xToken) {
            cout << "You Win!" << endl;
        } else
            play();
    }

The idea is I am trying to recursively keep playing if we don't have 3 elements in a row, column or diagonal that are the same value. The very problem now is to find how to read the board so it can find the 3 in a row so the game stops

Are you aware of that your code always deals with empty boards Board()? play() doesn't use any stored board, uses only newly created temporary boards.

arr[0] == arr[1] && arr[1] == arr[2], if you've got a bigger array it'd be better to use a loop

@3CxEZiVlQ Yes but is there a problem with that? Or would it be better if I did something else? My idea is to fill the indexes of the board with X's and O's as the game progresses

is play() a member of Board class ?

@Mahdy.n Yes it is

There is nothing wrong with your code, you just need someone to set it up for you, which is your job, but about your code problems, you shouldn't call constructor Board().  every time! Also want to check if rows or columns or diagonals are equal? So maybe you need 3 small functions to do this for you.

Please provide enough code so we see how you use this class. Currently there is only a class definition and a lose function which according to your comment belongs to the same class, but there is no driver code. Another comment: it is not good practice to mix I/O concerns with game logic. If play is a method, it should not ask the user for input, nor should it print the board; that should be done outside that class.

There is no need to worry about speed or efficiency here. Just check each of the rows, then each of the columns, then the two diagonals to see if they have three of the last player’s token. This becomes a simple method that you can call after every user input.

@Pelz04, since you are new in StackOverflow, I want to remember that there is the possibility to accept an answer by clicking on the check mark. It is important to note that it is not a mandate: choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. If no answer is considered the best solution, do nothing.

My bad @LoS, I did not know. A lot of your contributions have been really helpful no doubt, i appreciate it

It is possible to perform a quadratic-time check by verifying whether there is a row, column or diagonal that contains only the same symbol.
Provided the matrix m, which represents the tic-tac-toe table, it is checked whether there is a combination of type m[i][j] for j∈[0, 3), which indicates the rows, and for i∈[0, 3), which indicates the columns, other than the two diagonals m[i][i] and m[i][3 - i] for each i∈[0, 3). If one of these combinations contain only the same symbol, which can be either a nought or a cross, it means that a player has won, otherwise not.
To make the algorithm simpler, it is possible to exploit the following trick: provided that a specific number is used to represent the nought or cross, all cells of a certain row, column or diagonal are summed depeand then the resulting number is compared to two constants. In this way, if the sum is the multiple of 6 and one of the specific nunbers, it is possible to conclude that the row, column or diagonal contain only the corresponding symbol, and therefore the player has won. For example, the nough can be represented by the number -1 and likewise the cross can be represented by the number 1.
Example:
std::pair<bool, bool> is_winner()
{
  int sumb = 0;
  int sumd = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i != 3; ++i){
    int sumr = 0;
    int sumc = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j != 3 ; ++j){
      sumr += m[3 * i + j];
      sumc += m[3 * j + i];
    }
    if(sumr == -3 || sumc == -3)
      return {true, false};
    if(sumr == 3 || sumc == 3)
      return {false, true};
    sumb += m[i][i];
    sumd += m[i][3 - i];
  }
  if(sumb == -3 || sumd == -3)
    return {true, false};
  if(sumb == 3 || sumd == 3)
    return {false, true};
  return {false, false};
}


The nature of the game is such that some fields might be unfilled yet. If they are represented by 0, you should pick values carefully to represent x and o. For example, 1 and 2 are not suitable because a combination of 2 and "empty" can emulate a whole row of 1. For rows of size 6 one could use 1 and 7, and compare the sum to 6 and 42.

@anatolyg, thanks for the feedback. I think that it be possible to use a negative number for noughts and positive number for crosses.

As your class appears now, useful data elements are at odd indices in your grid array:
grid[1][1]
grid[1][3]
grid[1][5]
grid[3][1]
grid[3][3]
grid[3][5]
grid[5][1]
grid[5][3]
grid[5][5]

A bit inconvenient, but that will do for now.
You should first think about an interface for your code. I suggest the following:
class Board {
public:
...
    bool isWinningPosition(char token) const;
...
};

This method checks whether the given token appears in a whole row, a whole column or a whole diagonal. To implement it:
bool Board::isWinningPosition(char token) const
{
    // Check row 1
    // If the token appears at all 3 relevant positions, it wins!
    if (grid[1][1] == token && grid[1][3] == token && grid[1][5] == token)
        return true;

    // Check row 2
    if (...more conditions...)
        return true;

    // Check row 3, then 3 columns, then 2 diagonals, similar to the above

    // If all 8 conditions are false, the token doesn't win yet
    return false;
}

Here I hard-coded the 3x3 dimensions of the game. If you want to support flexible dimensions of the playing field, use some loops.

Regardless of the required logic, I suggest that you redesign your data storage. You should separate data from presentation. Have a 3x3 (not 6x6) array to hold the tokens, and this array should hold nothing else. This will make the printBoard method more complicated, but it will make every other method simpler.
